# Remove Excel footer bar from the display in a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, excel-web-access-webpart

I'm putting Excel graphs on a SharePoint page.

I have tried with "files and medias" and "embedded" web parts.

I always get that footer bar, and I would like to get rid of it.

Could someone help me with that?

Thank you.
[image]